# How to create multiple API using Node.js, Express, and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create multiple express API in node.js using the modal schema. The issue i am facing if i create more than two API then third one (last one) is not working.

As you can see in the below screenshot.  number 3.

showing all products.

showing single product.

not showing all categories.

1.**showing entire collection.**
[image]

2.**showing single row of collection based on ID.**
[image]

**3**.**showing collection of specific column.**
[image]

**here is module schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    category: String,
})

const PostModel = mongoose.model("products", ProductSchema) //"table name", UserSchema
module.exports = PostModel
```

**here is index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

//export module schema
const PostModel = require('./models/CreatePost')

// Middleware
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//define port
const port = 5000; 

//define database
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.jvxew8i.mongodb.net/store")



//find by table ID
app.get('/products/:_id', function(req, res) {
  PostModel.findById(req.params._id)
  .then(products => res.json(products))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
})


//find by table
app.get('/products', function(req, res) {
  PostModel.find()
  .then(products => res.json(products))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
})


//find by specific column
app.get('/products/categories', function(req, res) {
  PostModel.find({}, {category: 1, _id: 0})
  .then(products => res.json(products))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
})


// Server listen
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: I'M SORRY WHATdo you mean by **showing collection of specific column** YOU ARE USING MONGODB . what columnb are you talking about it's just a document no tables no columns

Comment: do you want to retrieve only  `category` field  to include  from the query

Comment: collection means table name., yes i am using mongDB. 
category is showing i am able to retrieve data of specific column but if there are more than 2 API then 3rd one last one is not working.
eg:  if i put app.get('/products/categories', function(req, res) { } at the top then it will work.

Comment: i made more info in the comments you can upvote my answer to help others having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overlapping get these two routes `'/products/categories'` and   `'/products/:_id'` .

thus, the route with url params `'/products/:_id'` was specified before the main route `'/products/categories'`  making it not accessible.

you have **to move this route**  :

```
//find by specific column
app.get('/products/categories', function(req, res) {
  PostModel.find({}, {category: 1, _id: 0})
  .then(products => res.json(products))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
})
```

**before this one  :**

```
//find by table ID
app.get('/products/:_id', function(req, res) {
  PostModel.findById(req.params._id)
  .then(products => res.json(products))
  .catch(err => res.json(err))
})
```

Comment: great, it is working. but why it is like that? thanks

Comment: well when you visit this path `'/products/categories'`  you're actually   visiting this one `'/products/:_id'` so  **categories** will be treated as an **_id** , because it comes first in you're app routes . that's way you are getting **castError** because it expecting an **objectId** and you are passing a string .  **Express just attempts to match your routes in the order they are defined**